# Regular expression match doesn't include space

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I have this regular expression:

```
(?'box_id'\d{1,19})","box_name":"(?'box_name'[\w\d\.\s]{1,19})
```

This works well, except when the box name contains spaces. For example, when executing it on `my box` it returns `mybox`, without the space.

How can I make it include spaces in the `box_name` group?

**Code:**

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"""object_id"":""(?<object_id>\d{1,19})"",""file_name"":""(?<file_name>[\w.]+(?:\s[\w.]+)*)""");
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(result);
if ( matches == null) throw new Exception("There was an error while parsing data."); 
if ( matches.Count > 0 )
{
  FileArchive.FilesDataTable filesdataTable = new FileArchive.FilesDataTable();
  foreach ( Match match in matches )
  {
    FileArchive.FilesRow row = filesdataTable.NewFilesRow();
    row.ID = match.Groups["object_id"].Value;
    row.Name = match.Groups["file_name"].Value;
  }
}
```

**Input:**

> {"objects":[{"object_id":"135248","file_name":"some space here.jpg","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"1"},{"object_id":"135257","file_name":"jup 13.jpg","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"1"},{"object_id":"135260","file_name":"my pic.jpg","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"1"},{"object_id":"135262","file_name":"EveningWav)es,Hon(olulu,Hawaii.jpg","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"1"},{"object_id":"135280","file_name":"test with spaces.jpg","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"1"}],"status":"ok"}

Comment: can you give us examples of the kind of strings you are trying to parse?

Comment: Something like :{"objects":[{"object_id":"135260","file_name":"my pic.jpg","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"1"},{"object_id":"135261","file_name":"New Text Document.txt","video_status":"0","thumbnail_status":"0"}],"status":"ok"}

Comment: Two file names here, my pic.jpg and New Text Document.txt

Comment: Err, if this is json, why don't you use a JSON parsing library?

Comment: I need special needs, JSON library is good but not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that your data is consistently double quote delimited, no?  That fact should be the basis of the regex:

```
(?<box_id>\d{1,19})","file_name":"(?<box_name>[^"]{1,19})  //1 to 19 non " chars.
```

As far as missing spaces, this token,  (?'box_name'[\w\d.\s]{1,19}) , cannot match 'mybox' on a string containing 'my box', so that issue must be downstream.

Typos and style:  you have the literal 'box_name' but the tokens are 'file_name'. Also, why in the world would you switch to using single quotes as the named group delimiter when <> brackets, the default, are MORE readable (since quotes are in the regex!)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. As for the double quotes, yes all my string are double quoted, I just removed here for simplicity, I also changed all ' to <>, you are right its better and yes its box_name, i made a mistake with file_name. However my space problem is still there when I replaced your [^"] approach, maybe the problem lies somewhere else, but this is what Matches collection gives me.

Comment: @user1091560 - The biggest problem is not posting the exact regex and source string. Thats because the regex that this requires is very simple. Post the relavent code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @sweaver2112 said, I think you need to expand the framing by adding quotes and get rid of the {1,19} range.

These regex's work in Perl, I don't want to crank up C# to test it.

`"(?<box_id>\d+)","(?:${type})":"(?<box_name>[\w.]+(?:\s[\w.]+)*)"`
or,
`"\s*(?<box_id>\d+)\s*","\s*(?:${type})\s*":"\s*(?<box_name>[\w.]+(?:\s[\w.]+)*)\s*"`
where $type = 'file_name';

Realistically though, this should work too (type is substituted). Its validation is relaxed.
`"(?<box_id>\d+)","file_name":"(?<box_name>[^"]*)"`

**edit**

"Not sure, what did my regex return to you? – sln yesterday
It returned correct results, in the input in my question i got 'somespacehere.jpg' 'jup13.jpg' and so on for file_name group. – NET Developer yesterday "

I took your code and input and just print the groups, it works perfect. The spaces are there,
something must be a problem with assigning it to your ROW data.

See it here http://www.ideone.com/HsTMF

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = @"{""objects"":[{""object_id"":""135248"",""file_name"":""some space here.jpg"",""video_status"":""0"",""thumbnail_status"":""1""},{""object_id"":""135257"",""file_name"":""jup 13.jpg"",""video_status"":""0"",""thumbnail_status"":""1""},{""object_id"":""135260"",""file_name"":""my pic.jpg"",""video_status"":""0"",""thumbnail_status"":""1""},{""object_id"":""135262"",""file_name"":""EveningWav)es,Hon(olulu,Hawaii.jpg"",""video_status"":""0"",""thumbnail_status"":""1""},{""object_id"":""135280"",""file_name"":""test with spaces.jpg"",""video_status"":""0"",""thumbnail_status"":""1""}],""status"":""ok""}";
      Regex reg = new Regex(
                   @"""object_id"":""(?<object_id>\d{1,19})"",""file_name"":""(?<file_name>[\w.]+(?:\s[\w.]+)*)"""
      );
      foreach ( Match match in reg.Matches(input) )
         Console.WriteLine(
                 "Id = '{0}',  File name = '{1}'", 
                 match.Groups["object_id"].Value,
                 match.Groups["file_name"].Value  );
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Id = '135248',  File name = 'some space here.jpg'
Id = '135257',  File name = 'jup 13.jpg'
Id = '135260',  File name = 'my pic.jpg'
Id = '135280',  File name = 'test with spaces.jpg'
```

Comment: Ok thanks, good points, is this even possible that a regex matches 'my box' but returns 'mybox' to me? If not i think my regex is working fine and i have to look somewhere else for this problem. also can it be something with regex options?

Comment: Not sure, what did my regex return to you?

Comment: It returned correct results, in the input in my question i got 'somespacehere.jpg' 'jup13.jpg' and so on for file_name group.

Comment: @NET Developer - No it works, there are spaces, try the code added in my edit.